# Iterate over string in python changing last digits

Tags: python, functional-programming

I wish to generate multiple strings on a list with the same prefix in python2.7, using python as a functional programming language:

I have the string '1234' and the string '5678' and I want to make a list of strings like this:
`['1234.1', '1234.2', '1234.3', '1234.4', '1234.5', '1234.6', '5678.1', '5678.2', '5678.3', '5678.4', '5678.5']`

I also can process these numbers as integers and after transform in string, there is no problem in that.
Can anybody help? 
I was able to do using for and replace, and I know this is no the most functional way :(

Comment: Can you explain please why `1234` goes to `6` and `5678` to `5`? Or `5` and `6` are just fixed numbers?

Comment: Why Python 2.7? It's almost at the end of its life cycle:https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: because the libraries that i am using demands 2.7

Comment: @AndrejKesely just numbers from 1 to 5 and from 1 to 6, fixed and sequential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try:

```
my_list = []
my_list.extend(['1234.%s' % e for e in range(1,7)])
my_list.extend(['5678.%s' % e for e in range(1,6)])
print(my_list)
# outpu: ['1234.1', '1234.2', '1234.3', '1234.4', '1234.5', '1234.6', '5678.1', '5678.2', '5678.3', '5678.4', '5678.5']
```